# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error but I think the code is okay

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

So I have a function that populates JTable from my database.

I have here

```
public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
try {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

    // Get the column names
    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
    columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
    }

    // Get all rows.
    Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {

                if(isObjectInteger(rs.getObject(i)) && i>1) //checks if the value is Integer else not and is past the first column
                {
                    System.out.println(i+"="+rs.getObject(i));
                    String label = columnNames.get(i); //THE ERROR IS ON THIS PART
                    newRow.addElement(getValue((Integer) rs.getObject(i),label)); //gets the value of specific foreign key id from another table
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println(i+"="+rs.getObject(i));
                    newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                } //inside row (new Rows)
    }

    rows.addElement(newRow); //outside row
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    return null;
}
}
```

I have total 8 columns in my database the output of that `System.out.println` is:

The one's that get's inside the else:

```
1=1
2=test
3=A.
4=test
5=test
6=test
```

The one's that get's inside the if

```
7=1
8=23
```

As you can see the output is right but it always throws Array index out of range: 8 error on the `String label = columnNames.get(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `ResultSet.getObject()` requires an argument based on one, `columnNames` is a vector, with its indexes based on zero.

Hence valid values for it would be `0..7`, *not* `1..8`. In other words, the first part of your `if` statement should be:

```
System.out.println(i + "=" + rs.getObject(i));
String label = columnNames.get(i-1); // NOT "i".
```

Comment: Thank you. I upvote this. I never saw that one. I was focused on other variables. Now i can go to sleep. I can accept this answer in 5 minutes

Comment: @Roch: sleep first, you can accept this answer anytime :-)